# When clicking Register button with empty field app crashes with error "NumberFormatException"

Tags: android, numberformatexception

my register is working fine, but i want to validate when the fields(EditText) are empty, if i click register the app crashes and if i leave an empty field it crashes too..

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);



    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            //test of error

            if (name.equals("") || username.equals("") || age == 0 || password.equals("")) {
                builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill in all the fileds").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create().show();

            } else {


                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(register.this, login.class);
                                register.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: **WILD GUESS** (since you didn't post your logcat): You still believe that `""` equals `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Integer age =null;
if(!etAge.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
 {
   age=Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
   }

            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            //test of error

            if (name.equals("") || username.equals("") || age == null || password.equals("")) {
                builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill in all the fileds").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create().show();
               return ;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you every much... its now working perfectly @Rishabh